# how can we access the array elements in cake php( in return[ elements ]) file name app.php

Tags: cakephp

```
use Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine;
use Cake\Database\Connection;
use Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql;
use Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer;
use Cake\Log\Engine\FileLog;
use Cake\Mailer\Transport\MailTransport;

return [

'App' => [
    'namespace' => 'App',
    'encoding' => env('APP_ENCODING', 'UTF-8'),
    'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_US'),
    'defaultTimezone' => env('APP_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'),
    'base' => false,
    'dir' => 'src',
    'webroot' => 'webroot',
    'wwwRoot' => WWW_ROOT,
    //'baseUrl' => env('SCRIPT_NAME'),
    'fullBaseUrl' => false,
    'imageBaseUrl' => 'img/',
    'cssBaseUrl' => 'css/',
    'jsBaseUrl' => 'js/',
    'paths' => [
        'plugins' => [ROOT . DS . 'plugins' . DS],
        'templates' => [APP . 'Template' . DS],
        'locales' => [APP . 'Locale' . DS],
    ],
],
```

]

**how can retrieve the variables in the return array?** it is in the cakephp3.8 version. Resides in cake/config/app.php

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is your default configuration file, first of all you need to include the following file at the top

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;
```

Then you can simply read as follows:

```
$appArray = Configure::read('App'); //This will return all values inside App as an array. You could print it.

$cssBaseUrl = Configure::read('App.cssBaseUrl'); //You can use dot notification to read the single value inside array.

$plugins = Configure::read('App.paths.plugins'); //You can even read deep level using multiple dots.
```

Comment: Thanks ascsoftw. but still an error exists.."In the case you tried to access a plugin controller make sure you added it to your composer file or you use the autoload option for the plugin."

Comment: Could you please share the code where you are trying to access. This looks like a different error.